# Flexure formula

Tags: civil-engineering

**The flexure formula is valid only for**

a. Static loads

b. Dynamic loads

c. Static load with negligible residual stress

d. Dynamic load with negligible residual stress

Comment: What is the question? Can you post the formula here? Is this homework? If you are a new user you can consider visiting the [tour] page to know more about the type of details to add into the question. Afterwards, use the [edit] link just below the question to edit it.